# Is there a graphical representation of the Lorentz transformation equations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I always loved theoretical physics as a kid and when I came upon this site while seeking computer advice via superuser I had to stick my silly little head into an oasis of intelligence.

I have often wondered what it would look like to view an object moving via the Lorentz transformation equations from a nominal speed of less than $c$ towards $c$ at an acceleration that a human could survive, let's say $3g$. And the space-time distance could be 100 light years. Would anyone be willing to produce a graph of this 1 dimension? I have tried to visualize it since I read "A Sophisticate's Primer of Relativity" 2nd Ed PW Bridgman when I was 19.

As a novice I always wanted an answer from a higher power and now I think I can get a response.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? If you're asking what relativistic objects look like to the eye then they appear to be rotated and they are **not** length contracted. This is known as [Terrell rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation).

Answer (score 3):

The best visualization of this that I know of is [A Slower Speed of Light](http://gamelab.mit.edu/games/a-slower-speed-of-light/), which is a simple game that allows you to move around at different fractions of the speed of light.